# How to turn Integer to enumeration value

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have an enum like this...

```
internal enum SomeType
{
    Type1 = 0, 
    Type2 = 1, 
    Type3 = 2
}
```

and I had an int like this...

```
int i = 1; // would return Type2...
```

How do I convert that int to the enum value?

Comment: It is quicker to search simple things like this than post a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

You can cast it directly

```
SomeType someType = (SomeType)i;
```